# Fetch common elements from List<Map<String,Object>> in Java

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I need to get the common elements from `List<Map<String,Object>>` and print that result. Below is the example where the result would be some json.

Ex:

```
[
    {
       "Id" : "123",
       "common" : [
       {
         "group":"abc",
         "department" : "xyz"
       },
       {
         "group":"abc",
         "department" : "zyx"
       }
     ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what the type of `Object`

```
 List<Map<String,Object>> o = ...
 Object common = o.get(0).get("common");
 // if object is of type Map<String, String>
 Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>) common;
```